# KendoUI Scheduler - Ignore timezone

Tags: kendo-ui, timezone, scheduler

In the Kendo Scheduler, using a custom edit form, how do you completely turn off its use of time zones?

I have attempted removing the kendo.timezones.min.js, removing the Timezone attribute from the scheduler control, and removing the event template UI elements related to time zones.

Comment: Does removing the `timezone` configuration property work? It should use the client's local time at that point.

Comment: Do you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use custom editor template where this editors are removed. Such example can be found in the scheduler documentation:

- [Scheduler: Custom editor template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/how-to/custom-edit-and-event-templates)

Also when binding to remote service is **highly recommended that the timezone option of the scheduler is set**. More information why is so important to have this option set can be found in the **[Timezones help article](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/timezones)**.

Answer (score 0):

I have straggled a lot with this. Basically you should:

1. set timezone of the scheduler component e.g. Etc/UTC
2. set timezone of the scheduler datasource
3. format the date you send from server using ISO8601

Comment: 3. format the date you send from server using ISO8601

Is there any example of doing this?

Comment: in PHP there is a declared constant and is easy as : date(DATE_ISO8601, time())